# Monodroid horizontalscrollview throws error frequently when scrolling

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, horizontalscrollview

I am using monodroid with a horizontalscrollview as the only child of a RelativeLayout. I am doing this in the code and it works fine for the first few seconds of scrolling and then it just freezes up and gives me the following error:

```
[SurfaceTextureClient] Fence::wait failed (Interrupted system call)
[ViewRootImpl] Could not lock surface
[ViewRootImpl] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:452)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2214)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2177)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[ViewRootImpl]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
[ViewRootImpl]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ViewRootImpl]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[ViewRootImpl]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
[ViewRootImpl]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
[ViewRootImpl]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm somewhat confused because it is a very simple activity, and I cannot find the cause of this scroll issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this only happens when running the project in debug. I believe this is an issue with the current version of Xamarin (4.0.12 Build 3)